# How should I properly design a vector normalization in opencl (work group sizes and kernels)

Tags: opencl, global, local, normalization

I am new to OpenCL and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around handling memory and local work groups.

I have a four dimensional data structure that is float[30][100][100][2025]. I currently iterate through the first two dimensions per normal, and pass the resulting 2025x100 matrix to the following CPU function.

```
// num_columns = 100; num_rows = 2025
for (int column = 0; column < num_cols; column++){
    vector = matrix[column];

    float min = vector[0];
    float max = vector[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        if(vector[i] < min){min = vector[i];}
        if(vector[i] > max){max = vector[i];}
    }
    float diff = max-min + epsilon;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        vector[i] = (vector[i]-min)/diff; //MULTI-THREAD HERE
    }

    float mean = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        mean += vector[i];
    }
    mean = mean/num_rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        vector[i] = vector[i]-mean + epsilon; //MULTI-THREAD HERE
    }

    float norm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        norm += vector[i]*vector[i];
    }
    norm = (float) sqrt(norm);

    if (norm > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            vector[i] = vector[i]/norm; //MULTI-THREAD HERE
        }
    }
}
```

I have commented where I believe I'd benefit from using OpenCL. It would be expensive to iterate through each column, write the vector the device buffer, perform the normalization, and then read it back to the host. The GPU (Adreno 330 on an htc one m8) has the memory to buffer the entire 2025x100 matrix at once. However, I have to flatten it into a 1d float array, and I don't know how to execute a kernel on only a portion of the buffer (a single vector) at a time.

I have been reading a lot about GPU architecture but I can't seem to wrap my head around the proper way to design this and whether or not I should be utilizing local workgroups to solve the problem. I hope I have provided enough information for someone to steer me in the right direction.

edit: I am aware there is a built-in CLnormalize function but I have three different normalization functions that I need to implement and I don't know if any of them would match the built-in. I tried to test it anyway but I received an error that it found no matching built-in function for normalize(float *vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily parallelize the complete function on the GPU, not just the parts you marked as "MULTI-THREAD HERE". In OpenCL your threads/work-items are divided into local workgroups. Within the same workgroup threads can work together, share data using local shared memory and synchronize using barriers. You can process one column in each workgroup. Each column is completely independent, so no synchronization between workgroups is needed.

Within each workgroup we can use each thread to process 4 or 8 elements of the vector. (If you would process only element per work-item, your workgroup would be bigger than the maximum workgroup size) The tricky part here is how to parallelize the calculation of max, min and sum of the vector: Here we can use a parallel programming primitive called "parallel reduction". Here is video with nice slides that explains the technique:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siHYfH1RQ_s

You can use this technique for sum of vector, minimum and maximum to calculate the minimum, maximum and average in parallel. If you do all three at the same time, it will even be a little bit faster than three separate reductions because you need to synchronize less often. You can also use local variables to store your temporary results of vector[i] and only read in vector[i] once at the beginning and write back vector[i] at the very end when all calculations on vector[i] have been done. That can save a lot of memory bandwidth.